# Retrieve chat users when isAdmin is set to true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a chat system using Spring boot. At this point I am required to display all the users where `isAdmin` field is set to `false` in the database.

This is the query for the getByAdmin in DAO class:

```
public User getByAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        return (User) getSession().createQuery(
                "from User where isAdmin = :isAdmin")
                .setParameter("isAdmin", isAdmin);
    }
```

In my controller.java this is the point where I am calling the above method to make the check if the admin is set to true:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-all-users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        try {
            boolean isAdmin = true;
            if(_userDao.getByAdmin(isAdmin).equals(true))
            {
            return _userDao.getAll();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in fetching users: ", e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this is my bean definition for the Users.java

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long timestamp;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean isAdmin;
```

this is where I am making the check so nothing was returned

```
try {
            boolean isAdmin = true;
            if(_userDao.getByAdmin(isAdmin).equals(true))
            {
            return _userDao.getAll();
            }
```

if I remove the above check I will be able to see all users

My challenge is that nothing was returned calling `getAllUsers` method.

Please what could be wrong with my logic?

Comment: How do you cal that endpoint? How did you understand that nothing has returned?

Comment: check to see my edits

Comment: because an empty list was returned whereby I have admin set to true from the back end

Comment: have you put users with isAdmin = true in your database?

Comment: Yes I have done that. I am actually using mysql database

Comment: (List<User>) getSession().createQuery(
                "from User where isAdmin = :isAdmin")
                .setParameter("isAdmin", isAdmin).list(); <- because you have to send it and all queries (except modifying) are SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
if(_userDao.getByAdmin(isAdmin).equals(true))
```

You are comparing `User` with `boolean`. Probably you wanted to check something like:

```
if(_userDao.getByAdmin(isAdmin) != null)
```

?

Comment: Still it returned empty list. How am I sure that my query construct is okay

Comment: Is there a way I can test my query result before using it to know what it actually returns

Comment: @Learner use debuger

Comment: to see if your query is ok, you should enable hibernate to LOG your queries, that are done with hibernate. then you can look at it in logs. Note that they're written in HQL without actual values,